# I`m just curious about how to speak "anti-" is correct?

Tags: pronunciation, prefixes

I`m just curious about how to speak "anti-" is correct?

it`s like ant/ai/ or ant/i/??

Comment: Have you tried looking it up in dictionaries? You’ll find both pronunciations there, and if it’s a decent dictionary, it’ll even tell you that the /aɪ/ pronunciation is mainly American English, while the /i/ pronunciation is mainly British English.

Comment: Why is this tagged pronouns? "anti-" is a prefix. I speak American and I say "anti-" with /aɪ/ when dictating the word it in isolation (e.g. in this discussion). If it appears as part of another word (the normal case), then my pronunciation might be influenced by the word it is attached to.

Comment: @Brandin thx, guys. for example like anti-social, how to pronounce?
If they are both correct, no matter which one I pronouns is acceptable by native speakers, right?

Comment: @ellis Basic answer already mentioned above, basically there is no "right answer" here. If you're learning as a second language, find a pronunciation model that you like and then imitate it.

Comment: Alright, Thx a lot to both of u.

Comment: @ellis - have you confused pronouns with pronounce? pronouns is the plural of pronoun, and has absolutely nothing to do with pronunciation.

Comment: Oh yes @AndyT, thx for correcting my usage.